# Can we submit iOS app for facebook login review while app is not completed still development?

Tags: ios, facebook

Hi I'm developing an iOS app where I'm using Facebook login integration.From facebook i want to get user birthday for that i need to submit my app to facebook but my app is still at starting stage can I submit my app in development stage to get details or is there any other way to get details from facebook in development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Facebook developer dashboard, go to the roles section for your app. You will have to set roles for user to be able to access your app while its still under development. You can add roles as "Testers", "Developer" or "Administrator" and all these users will have access to your app while its still under Development and hasn't been approved by Facebook.

**Edit:**
From the facebook requirements page-

> We ask that you provide test users with your app submission so that we
>   have the necessary credentials to test and access your app. This way,
>   our review experience is equivalent to your app's experience.

For further information regarding facebook acceptance criteria and their processes, checkout [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/requirements) link

**Edit:**
If you want just the basic information, you can open your app dashboard on Facebook. You will see *App Review* button. Click on it and it will show a page where there will be an option to make the app public. Turning it on will allow other users to use your app without you having to submit it to Facebook. This however allows you limited integrations from Facebook. From the docs:

> If your app asks for more than public_profile, email and user_friends,
>   Facebook must review it before you release it. Learn more about the
>   review process and what's required to pass review.

Comment: Thanks Rikh, and If i want to submit my app for getting details from all users. is it mandatory to complete my app development

Comment: Well I'm not sure if you can get away with offering minimum app functionality and submitting it for review to facebook but I'd suggest completing the application first as they do mention on their page that they will be testing the application. Check me edit for more info.